# Sign Of Derivatives and Local Extremum

Tags: calculus

Consider a differentiable function $f(x)$ on the interval $[a, b]$, such that it has no local Extremum on this interval then prove that $f(x)$ is monotonic on the interval $[a, b]$.
$$$$If $f'(x)$ is entirely non-negative or non-positive then we are done and if not then there exists $$a \leq c < d \leq b$$ such that $f'(c)$ and $f'(d)$ are of opposite signs. Now if $f'(x)$ takes the value $0$ at a finite number of points in $[c, d]$ say at $x_1, x_2, .... x_n$ then divide the interval $[c, d]$ into $$[c, x_1]; [x_1, x_2]; ..... ; [x_{n-1}, x_n]; [x_n, b]$$. Now consider any arbitrary subinterval say $[x_k, x_{k+1}]$ then in the open interval $(x_k, x_{k+1})$ $f'(x)$ is entirely positive or negative as derivatives have the intermediate value property. And hence there is a point $x_{k_0}$ passing through which $f'(x)$ must change it's sign because if it would have not changed its sign passing through any of the $x_k$ then $f'(c)$ and $f'(d)$ would have same sign. And hence there is a local Extremum at some point in $[a, b]$ which contradicts the given hypothesis, and hence $f'(x)$ is either entirely non-negative or non-positive.
$$$$I want to know that is the Theorem Correct even when $f'(x)$ takes the value $0$ at infinite number of points or is there a counterexample.